# Shading Issues with the Array Modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, artifacts

I'm working on a model of a car wheel. However, before I continue, I want to fix some shading issues I am having.

My model has *Subdivision surface*, *Mirror*, and *Array* modifiers, which make up the 10 spokes/"slices" of the wheel. The wheel itself is all one, contiguous object. However, there are multiple areas where the shading looks a bit odd.

### Problem #1: Seams at the End of Array

While my *Array* modifier has *Merge Vertices* checked and all angle values were precisely calculated/typed in to ensure that all of the vertices in the circle line up, the very last seam where the last segment connects with the first does not merge.

[image]

[image]

I think that this is because the *Array* modifier merges vertices only with each next part. Even turning on Automerge editing to merge vertices that are close enough globally does not work, because of the Array being a modifier and not applied. I have tested applying this modifier, and the problems did go away. However, **I wish to keep it in an array and was wondering if anyone has any other solutions**.

### Problem #2: Hard Edges on Circle

At the center of the wheel, where all of the spokes converge, **there is a circular edge which appears to not be affected by the *Subdivision surface* modifier.**

[image]

[image]

No, it is not marked a hard edge -- it is completely parallel with the two lines in front and behind it too, but those are completely curved as normal.

### Problem #3: Artifacts at all Array Seams

In the indicated center part of the model, **there is a shading artifact**. It happens where each part of the array has a seam.

[image]

Does anyone have any advice? It would be best if you could download the .blend file to mess with it:

[image]

But either way, I'm happy to have any feedback on the best way to fix these various artifacts from those more experienced than me. Thank you so much!

Comment: 1 - You need to enable the First Last option in the Array modifier. 2 - I don't know a lot about Crease but depending on your topology it won't always create a 100% sharp edge. 3 - It's not really a shading artefact, your topology creates this pinching, you need to correct it

Answer (score 2):

For the first issue, you just need to *'merge first last'* in the array modifier. This option tells Blender that the extremities of the array have to be merged.

[image]

For the second one, it is because the flat face normal is inverted. Select your mesh and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.

[image]

An easy way to check if normals are inverted is to turn on x-ray:

[image]

The third one is because the wheel border is not 'regular'. To make it more regular, use the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> to make a loop along the wheel border.

That will make a ngon (on the face above) but luckily that doesn't matter here. Eventually, turn it to quad+tri (not shown in the gif below).

[image]